# d3.js and Sankey diagram error

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I'm struggling to get my first Sankey made the data is pretty simple:

```
            Discharge   OBS ADM     FULL ADM    Total
Station 1   1725        610         708         3043
Station 2   1095        424         464         1983
Station 3   1652        24          27          1703
```

So, I was thinking of creating the nodes and links in the following fashion - which was unsuccessful:

```
{
"nodes":[
{"name":"All Patients"},
{"name":"Station 1"},
{"name":"Station 2"},
{"name":"Station 3"},
{"name":"Discharge"},
{"name":"Obs Admission"},
{"name":"Full Admission"}
],
"links":[
{"source":"All Patients","target":"Station 1","value":3.043},
{"source":"All Patients","target":"Station 2","value":1.983},
{"source":"All Patients","target":"Station 3","value":1.703},
{"source":"Station 1","target":"Discharge","value":1.725},
{"source":"Station 2","target":"Discharge","value":1.095},
{"source":"Station 3","target":"Discharge","value":1.652},
{"source":"Station 1","target":"Obs Admission","value":.610},
{"source":"Station 2","target":"Obs Admission","value":.424},
{"source":"Station 3","target":"Obs Admission","value":.024},
{"source":"Station 1","target":"Full Admission","value":.708},
{"source":"Station 2","target":"Full Admission","value":.464},
{"source":"Station 3","target":"Full Admission","value":.027},
]}
```

Using this index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SANKEY Experiment</title>
<style>

.node rect {
  cursor: move;
  fill-opacity: .9;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-opacity: .2;
}

.link:hover {
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}

</style>
<body>

<p id="chart">

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="sankey.js"></script>
<script>

var units = "Widgets";

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatNumber = d3.format(",.0f"),    // zero decimal places
    format = function(d) { return formatNumber(d) + " " + units; },
    color = d3.scale.category20();

// append the svg canvas to the page
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Set the sankey diagram properties
var sankey = d3.sankey()
    .nodeWidth(36)
    .nodePadding(40)
    .size([width, height]);

var path = sankey.link();

// load the data
d3.json("sankey-formatted-names.json", function(error, graph) {

    var nodeMap = {};
    graph.nodes.forEach(function(x) { nodeMap[x.name] = x; });
    graph.links = graph.links.map(function(x) {
      return {
        source: nodeMap[x.source],
        target: nodeMap[x.target],
        value: x.value
      };
    });

  sankey
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .layout(32);

// add in the links
  var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; });

// add the link titles
  link.append("title")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.source.name + " → " + 
                d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

// add in the nodes
  var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
    .call(d3.behavior.drag()
      .origin(function(d) { return d; })
      .on("dragstart", function() { 
          this.parentNode.appendChild(this); })
      .on("drag", dragmove));

// add the rectangles for the nodes
  node.append("rect")
      .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy; })
      .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
      .style("fill", function(d) { 
          return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, "")); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { 
          return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2); })
    .append("title")
      .text(function(d) { 
          return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

// add in the title for the nodes
  node.append("text")
      .attr("x", -6)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("transform", null)
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
    .filter(function(d) { return d.x < width / 2; })
      .attr("x", 6 + sankey.nodeWidth())
      .attr("text-anchor", "start");

// the function for moving the nodes
  function dragmove(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", 
        "translate(" + d.x + "," + (
                d.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(height - d.dy, d3.event.y))
            ) + ")");
    sankey.relayout();
    link.attr("d", path);
  }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this sankey.js:

```
d3.sankey = function() {
  var sankey = {},
      nodeWidth = 24,
      nodePadding = 8,
      size = [1, 1],
      nodes = [],
      links = [];

  sankey.nodeWidth = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return nodeWidth;
    nodeWidth = +_;
    return sankey;
  };

  sankey.nodePadding = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return nodePadding;
    nodePadding = +_;
    return sankey;
  };

  sankey.nodes = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return nodes;
    nodes = _;
    return sankey;
  };

  sankey.links = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return links;
    links = _;
    return sankey;
  };

  sankey.size = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return size;
    size = _;
    return sankey;
  };

  sankey.layout = function(iterations) {
    computeNodeLinks();
    computeNodeValues();
    computeNodeBreadths();
    computeNodeDepths(iterations);
    computeLinkDepths();
    return sankey;
  };

  sankey.relayout = function() {
    computeLinkDepths();
    return sankey;
  };

  sankey.link = function() {
    var curvature = .5;

    function link(d) {
      var x0 = d.source.x + d.source.dx,
          x1 = d.target.x,
          xi = d3.interpolateNumber(x0, x1),
          x2 = xi(curvature),
          x3 = xi(1 - curvature),
          y0 = d.source.y + d.sy + d.dy / 2,
          y1 = d.target.y + d.ty + d.dy / 2;
      return "M" + x0 + "," + y0
           + "C" + x2 + "," + y0
           + " " + x3 + "," + y1
           + " " + x1 + "," + y1;
    }

    link.curvature = function(_) {
      if (!arguments.length) return curvature;
      curvature = +_;
      return link;
    };

    return link;
  };

  // Populate the sourceLinks and targetLinks for each node.
  // Also, if the source and target are not objects, assume they are indices.
  function computeNodeLinks() {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      node.sourceLinks = [];
      node.targetLinks = [];
    });
    links.forEach(function(link) {
      var source = link.source,
          target = link.target;
      if (typeof source === "number") source = link.source = nodes[link.source];
      if (typeof target === "number") target = link.target = nodes[link.target];
      source.sourceLinks.push(link);
      target.targetLinks.push(link);
    });
  }

  // Compute the value (size) of each node by summing the associated links.
  function computeNodeValues() {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      node.value = Math.max(
        d3.sum(node.sourceLinks, value),
        d3.sum(node.targetLinks, value)
      );
    });
  }

  // Iteratively assign the breadth (x-position) for each node.
  // Nodes are assigned the maximum breadth of incoming neighbors plus one;
  // nodes with no incoming links are assigned breadth zero, while
  // nodes with no outgoing links are assigned the maximum breadth.
  function computeNodeBreadths() {
    var remainingNodes = nodes,
        nextNodes,
        x = 0;

    while (remainingNodes.length) {
      nextNodes = [];
      remainingNodes.forEach(function(node) {
        node.x = x;
        node.dx = nodeWidth;
        node.sourceLinks.forEach(function(link) {
          nextNodes.push(link.target);
        });
      });
      remainingNodes = nextNodes;
      ++x;
    }

    //
    moveSinksRight(x);
    scaleNodeBreadths((width - nodeWidth) / (x - 1));
  }

  function moveSourcesRight() {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      if (!node.targetLinks.length) {
        node.x = d3.min(node.sourceLinks, function(d) { return d.target.x; }) - 1;
      }
    });
  }

  function moveSinksRight(x) {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      if (!node.sourceLinks.length) {
        node.x = x - 1;
      }
    });
  }

  function scaleNodeBreadths(kx) {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      node.x *= kx;
    });
  }

  function computeNodeDepths(iterations) {
    var nodesByBreadth = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.x; })
        .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
        .entries(nodes)
        .map(function(d) { return d.values; });

    //
    initializeNodeDepth();
    resolveCollisions();
    for (var alpha = 1; iterations > 0; --iterations) {
      relaxRightToLeft(alpha *= .99);
      resolveCollisions();
      relaxLeftToRight(alpha);
      resolveCollisions();
    }

    function initializeNodeDepth() {
      var ky = d3.min(nodesByBreadth, function(nodes) {
        return (size[1] - (nodes.length - 1) * nodePadding) / d3.sum(nodes, value);
      });

      nodesByBreadth.forEach(function(nodes) {
        nodes.forEach(function(node, i) {
          node.y = i;
          node.dy = node.value * ky;
        });
      });

      links.forEach(function(link) {
        link.dy = link.value * ky;
      });
    }

    function relaxLeftToRight(alpha) {
      nodesByBreadth.forEach(function(nodes, breadth) {
        nodes.forEach(function(node) {
          if (node.targetLinks.length) {
            var y = d3.sum(node.targetLinks, weightedSource) / d3.sum(node.targetLinks, value);
            node.y += (y - center(node)) * alpha;
          }
        });
      });

      function weightedSource(link) {
        return center(link.source) * link.value;
      }
    }

    function relaxRightToLeft(alpha) {
      nodesByBreadth.slice().reverse().forEach(function(nodes) {
        nodes.forEach(function(node) {
          if (node.sourceLinks.length) {
            var y = d3.sum(node.sourceLinks, weightedTarget) / d3.sum(node.sourceLinks, value);
            node.y += (y - center(node)) * alpha;
          }
        });
      });

      function weightedTarget(link) {
        return center(link.target) * link.value;
      }
    }

    function resolveCollisions() {
      nodesByBreadth.forEach(function(nodes) {
        var node,
            dy,
            y0 = 0,
            n = nodes.length,
            i;

        // Push any overlapping nodes down.
        nodes.sort(ascendingDepth);
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          node = nodes[i];
          dy = y0 - node.y;
          if (dy > 0) node.y += dy;
          y0 = node.y + node.dy + nodePadding;
        }

        // If the bottommost node goes outside the bounds, push it back up.
        dy = y0 - nodePadding - size[1];
        if (dy > 0) {
          y0 = node.y -= dy;

          // Push any overlapping nodes back up.
          for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
            node = nodes[i];
            dy = node.y + node.dy + nodePadding - y0;
            if (dy > 0) node.y -= dy;
            y0 = node.y;
          }
        }
      });
    }

    function ascendingDepth(a, b) {
      return a.y - b.y;
    }
  }

  function computeLinkDepths() {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      node.sourceLinks.sort(ascendingTargetDepth);
      node.targetLinks.sort(ascendingSourceDepth);
    });
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      var sy = 0, ty = 0;
      node.sourceLinks.forEach(function(link) {
        link.sy = sy;
        sy += link.dy;
      });
      node.targetLinks.forEach(function(link) {
        link.ty = ty;
        ty += link.dy;
      });
    });

    function ascendingSourceDepth(a, b) {
      return a.source.y - b.source.y;
    }

    function ascendingTargetDepth(a, b) {
      return a.target.y - b.target.y;
    }
  }

  function center(node) {
    return node.y + node.dy / 2;
  }

  function value(link) {
    return link.value;
  }

  return sankey;
};
```

It didn't work... not sure why. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Alfa

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, looks like couple very minor mistakes.

1) You have an extra comma at the end of your links `{"source":"Station 3","target":"Full Admission","value":.027}**,**` so use updated sankey-formatted-names.json file without extra comma below. I like to use JSON validator https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to confirm if valid JSON file.

2) Also, I looked at an example JSON file at http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5028304 and they have the values in double quotes. Since you have source and target as strings, then looks like value must also be a string. If you have source and target as numeric, then value can be numeric.

```
{
"nodes":[
{"name":"All Patients"},
{"name":"Station 1"},
{"name":"Station 2"},
{"name":"Station 3"},
{"name":"Discharge"},
{"name":"Obs Admission"},
{"name":"Full Admission"}
],
"links":[
{"source":"All Patients","target":"Station 1","value":"3.043"},
{"source":"All Patients","target":"Station 2","value":"1.983"},
{"source":"All Patients","target":"Station 3","value":"1.703"},
{"source":"Station 1","target":"Discharge","value":"1.725"},
{"source":"Station 2","target":"Discharge","value":"1.095"},
{"source":"Station 3","target":"Discharge","value":"1.652"},
{"source":"Station 1","target":"Obs Admission","value":"0.610"},
{"source":"Station 2","target":"Obs Admission","value":"0.424"},
{"source":"Station 3","target":"Obs Admission","value":"0.024"},
{"source":"Station 1","target":"Full Admission","value":"0.708"},
{"source":"Station 2","target":"Full Admission","value":"0.464"},
{"source":"Station 3","target":"Full Admission","value":"0.027"}
]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Justin. Really appreciate the help and expertise!